# HQL Query to check whether table has data or not

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Initially database created it doesn't have any table. I write code to update values using parameterised query but value doesn't exist initially then how we can handle it?

Comment: If there are no tables in database, how are you making a query to the table. Make sure you are asking right question. Do you mean to say that database table is there, but it has no data. And you have to handle updated queries in case there is no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
public Boolean existsOrNot (DTOAny i) {
    Query q = getSession().             
    createQuery("select 1 from DTOAny t where t.key = :key");
        q.setString("key", i.getKey() );
    return (q.uniqueResult() != null);
}
```

(*Assuming that the table exists and you are checking that there is data in the table or not*)

Comment: @Jeevan Patil just check out answer which is given by Rahul Tripathi it worked properly